# grep only the third column but return entire line

Tags: grep

I want to grep for things in only the third column with '6-1' in the beginning. So something like '6-1*blahblah' should be caught and I'd like the entire line to be outputted. I'm wondering what the correct syntax for this is?

A line of sample input would include:

```
hg19_gold_AL122127.6-109525 0   1-18*anc    1   18  65S185M *   0   0   GAGAAACCAGGCCAGTCATGTGAGACTTCACCCACTCCTGTGTCCTCTCCACAGGTGCCCACTCCCAGGTTCAGCTGGTGCAGTCTGGAGCTGAGGTGAAGAAGCCTGGGGCCTCAGTGAAGGTCTCCTGCAAGGCTTCTGGTTACACCTTTACCAGCTATGGTATCAGCTGGGTGCGACAGGCCCCTGGACAAGGGCTTGAGTGGATGGGATGGATCAGCGCTTACAATGGTAACACAAACTATGCACA  ?????@<BBDB@EDDDFGCG+FIFHIHHHFD>HIHII>AHHIIF5IHHHGIHDFEFHHGHHHHHIIFIDIGBAHIBHDH=BHIHG;IHHHFHF+HIHIIHDHGFI=H=H=FGG?FH7HHCHGGHGHHGDHFADEGFG2GFD@GGGGGBGCGEEGF*EGAGGFCFEFFGGFC0E;GCGEGCEFEFAEEGEE0EEGGECGGAGFEEEG?GCEHHHHF*ECF?G<FGEGFGAGGEEEEAGA8GE?GGEC?EGF  AS:i:37
hg38_gold_AC246787.2-87811  16  6-1*anc 259 2   47M203S *   AACTCTGTGACTCCCGAGGACACGGCTGTGTATTACTGTGCAAGAGACACAGTGAGGGGAAGTCAGTGTGAGCCCAGACACAAACCTCCCTGCAGGGATGCTCAGGACCCCAGAAGGCACCCAGCACTACCAGCGCAGGGCCCAGACCAGGAGCAGGTGTGGAGTTAAGCAAAAATGGAACTTCTTGCTGTGTCTTAAACTGTTGTTGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGCTCAGCAACAGAGATCATAGAAAA  CGFEGEG:C:G4E;CGEE*CC?G:?GG?GGECFCHFAECF:FAFEG*GGE6?0GCGE;GGEFFCEG:GGG/ECGG+GGF?2GEGGEGDGEEEEEF/EECGGGGGEGGGFGGGGGEGDGEHGEFGF5EG=GGFEHGDFHFHEEIHGGFHHFGGIHGHHHHHI-IHIHHIIEFICIIAHGHFHHIHIDGFCHHIHEHHIIFIDIHIHHGHFIIGIHFIFIEHHIFIIHHIFFGFFFDDE?DDDEBBB?????  AS:i:94 XS:i:68 XN:i:0  XM:i:0  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:0  MD:Z:47 YT:Z:UU
```

but the output should only be the second line

```
hg38_gold_AC246787.2-87811  16  6-1*anc 259 2   47M203S *   AACTCTGTGACTCCCGAGGACACGGCTGTGTATTACTGTGCAAGAGACACAGTGAGGGGAAGTCAGTGTGAGCCCAGACACAAACCTCCCTGCAGGGATGCTCAGGACCCCAGAAGGCACCCAGCACTACCAGCGCAGGGCCCAGACCAGGAGCAGGTGTGGAGTTAAGCAAAAATGGAACTTCTTGCTGTGTCTTAAACTGTTGTTGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGCTCAGCAACAGAGATCATAGAAAA  CGFEGEG:C:G4E;CGEE*CC?G:?GG?GGECFCHFAECF:FAFEG*GGE6?0GCGE;GGEFFCEG:GGG/ECGG+GGF?2GEGGEGDGEEEEEF/EECGGGGGEGGGFGGGGGEGDGEHGEFGF5EG=GGFEHGDFHFHEEIHGGFHHFGGIHGHHHHHI-IHIHHIIEFICIIAHGHFHHIHIDGFCHHIHEHHIIFIDIHIHHGHFIIGIHFIFIEHHIFIIHHIFFGFFFDDE?DDDEBBB?????  AS:i:94 XS:i:68 XN:i:0  XM:i:0  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:0  MD:Z:47 YT:Z:UU
```

Comment: Please post both sample input and sample output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `awk`, you can do:

```
awk '$3~/^6-1/' file
hg38_gold_AC246787.2-87811  16  6-1*anc 259 2   47M203S *   AACTCTGTGACTCCCGAGGACACGGCTGTGTATTACTGTGCAAGAGACACAGTGAGGGGAAGTCAGTGTGAGCCCAGACACAAACCTCCCTGCAGGGATGCTCAGGACCCCAGAAGGCACCCAGCACTACCAGCGCAGGGCCCAGACCAGGAGCAGGTGTGGAGTTAAGCAAAAATGGAACTTCTTGCTGTGTCTTAAACTGTTGTTGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGCTCAGCAACAGAGATCATAGAAAA  CGFEGEG:C:G4E;CGEE*CC?G:?GG?GGECFCHFAECF:FAFEG*GGE6?0GCGE;GGEFFCEG:GGG/ECGG+GGF?2GEGGEGDGEEEEEF/EECGGGGGEGGGFGGGGGEGDGEHGEFGF5EG=GGFEHGDFHFHEEIHGGFHHFGGIHGHHHHHI-IHIHHIIEFICIIAHGHFHHIHIDGFCHHIHEHHIIFIDIHIHHGHFIIGIHFIFIEHHIFIIHHIFFGFFFDDE?DDDEBBB?????  AS:i:94 XS:i:68 XN:i:0  XM:i:0  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:0  MD:Z:47 YT:Z:UU
```

It will only get lines where third filed starts with `6-1`